# Generating user content in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jython

For non-technical reasons I need to keep generating user content in Jenkins.

Theoretically I could do smth like:

- have parameterized build
- provide webpage in user content folder that does GET/POST to parameterized build
- display webpage with results (I don't even know if it's possible)

UPDATE: That is, I want to run some dynamic webpage in Jenkins (yes I know it does not look very good). Specifically, Jenkins users after logging in need some additional functionality like generating paths and hashes from job workspaces and have them displayed and running such logic as a separate Jenkins job is not very attractive (user content folder is simply the most appropriate place for such stuff I think). Typically, I'd provide such features using say simple Django webpage, but that's not an option for various reasons.

Comment: I don't quite understand the context; ist is 1.) there is some input and it it Jenkins' task to post the input some content management system (like Jenkins replacing a user) or 2.) some users are the source of user generated content and Jenkins publishes them?

Comment: So how do the Jenkins users provide new content? By putting data somewhere accessible on a path and then starting a Jenkins process?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @Slav: doing smth like running PHP webpage, but using Jenkins facilities only

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do this:

- install Scriptler plugin
- write Groovy script that implements some additional functionality needed by Jenkins users
- write webpage that uses Javascript + jQuery to use form elements' values for GET/POST to Groovy script, update the webpage dynamically (say by replacing html `body` or adding to it), put it in `userContent`
- grant selected Jenkins users `Run script` permission in the Jenkins' security matrix config